# Define function that takes arguments from multiple vectors sequentially

Tags: r, function

See how addition works over components:

```
a<-1:3
a+a  #Gives (1+1), (2+2), (3+3)
```

I've considered using loops over argument lengths or transforming them into a data.frame and then using `apply` but I have the intuition there is a more efficient way of going about this.

Specifically, I'd like to calculate the mean of each set of components ignoring zero values, like so:

```
function(x) {
  mean(x[x!=0])
}
```

Except `x` would be the i-th components of an arbitrary amount of arguments.

Comment: "Except x would be the first components of an arbitrary amount of arguments." Do you want to ignore the non-first elements? Or do you want to have the means of the firsts, the means of the seconds, etc.?

Comment: Yikes. You guys are fast. I edited that for clarity. If I have `x<-1:3` and `y<-10:30` I'd like this function to operate on `c(1,10)`, `c(2,20)`, `c(3,30)` and so on.

Comment: Use `outer(x,y,fun)` for that, probably. By the way, you should edit that sort of concrete example into the question, not leave it to a comment.

Comment: `outer` works for 2. If you have more than that, then using `apply` on a matrix seems natural.

Comment: Do you mean `y <- seq(10, 30, by = 10)`, or is the function supposed to scale and skip intermediary values?

Comment: Ideally it would work like + and just loop over the smaller argument. I'm going to edit my original post because it's missing a lot of conext I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `mapply` or its wrapper `Map` would work fairly well here.

```
mapply(function(...) {temp <- c(...); mean(temp[temp != 0])}, 1:10, 11:20)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

With `mapply`, the given function is applied to the collection of the first elements of each vector, then the collection of the second elements and so on. The function creates a new vector with `c` and then calculates the mean for all non-zero elements. This function returns an atomic vector.

```
Map(function(...) {temp <- c(...); mean(temp[temp != 0])}, 1:10, 11:20)
```

returns a list instead. This could be wrapped in `unlist` to return a vector.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'm sorry I phrased my initial question so poorly.

Answer (score 2):

If we need to do this sequentially from multiple vectors

```
Reduce(`+`, listofvectors)
```

Or `rbind` or `cbind` it to create a `matrix` and then do the `colSums` or `rowSums`

```
colSums(m1)
```

#### Update

Regarding the second part of the question (not clear), if it is to get the `mean` of individual `vector`s in a `list` excluding the 0 value

```
sapply(listofvectors, function(x) mean(x[x!=0]))
```

Or if we need the `mean` of sequence of elements in the `matrix` (created by `rbind`ing the `vector`s), then `replace` the 0 values with `NA`, and get the `colMeans` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
colMeans(replace(m1, m1==0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
colMeans(replace(m2, m2==0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

NOTE: The `colMeans` and `matrix` approach are vectorized.  No looping done here

#### data

```
a1 <- 1:5
b1 <- 6:10
c1 <- 11:15
listofvectors <- list(a1, b1, c1)
m1 <- rbind(a1, b1, c1)
m2 <- rbind(1:10, 11:20)
```